# Prove that, for every natural n, $\sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}=\prod_{p|n}(1-\frac{1}{p})$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that, for every natural n, $\sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}=\prod_{p|n}(1-\frac{1}{p})$ and conclude that $\phi(n)=n \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}$.

Proof of $\sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}=\prod_{p|n}(1-\frac{1}{p})$:

I am havent trouble doing the proof of this statement,

Proof of $\phi(n)=n \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}$:

By definition, the Euler phi-function is given by $\phi(n)=\sum_{m \leq n,(m,n)=1}1.$ Eliminating the coprimality condition $\gcd(m,n)=1$ yields

$\phi(n)=\sum_{m \leq n} \sum_{d| \gcd(m,n)} \mu(n)=\sum_{d|n} \mu(n) \sum_{m \leq n, d|m}1 = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \frac{n}{d}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note that the left side and right side of the identities you are trying to prove are multiplicative, so you only need to prove the results for prime powers, which is not hard.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an informal approach, but it is honest work. Suppose that the prime factors of $n$ are $p_1,\ldots,p_k$, distinct. Then $$\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac 1p\right)=1-\sum \frac{1}{p_i}+\sum\frac 1{p_ip_j}-\cdots+(-1)^k\frac{1}{p_1\cdots p_k}=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu(d)}d$$

since the non-square-free factors vanish, and those that are square-free are precisely those listed in the middle, the sign being the one given by $\mu$.